# Iterating over ChronicleMap results in Exception

Tags: chronicle-map

I am using v3.10.1 of Chronicle Map. In my map, I have approximately 77K entries. I am trying to iterate through this map using `entrySet()` method. It doesn't iterate successfully and in between throws Chronicle specific exception. Here are the logs produced from Chronicle Map

```
016-09-17 06:39:15 [ERROR] n.o.c.m.i.CompiledMapIterationContext - Contexts locked on this segment:
net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapIterationContext@205cd34b: used, segment 62, local state: UNLOCKED, read lock count: 0, update lock count: 0, write lock count: 0
Current thread contexts:
net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapIterationContext@205cd34b: used, segment 62, local state: UNLOCKED, read lock count: 0, update lock count: 0, write lock count: 0
```

and Exception:

```
2016-09-17 06:39:15 [ERROR] akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation - Failed to acquire the lock in 60 seconds.
Possible reasons:
 - The lock was not released by the previous holder. If you use contexts API,
 for example map.queryContext(key), in a try-with-resources block.
 - This Chronicle Map (or Set) instance is persisted to disk, and the previous
 process (or one of parallel accessing processes) has crashed while holding
 this lock. In this case you should use ChronicleMapBuilder.recoverPersistedTo() procedure
 to access the Chronicle Map instance.
 - A concurrent thread or process, currently holding this lock, spends
 unexpectedly long time (more than 60 seconds) in
 the context (try-with-resource block) or one of overridden interceptor
 methods (or MapMethods, or MapEntryOperations, or MapRemoteOperations)
 while performing an ordinary Map operation or replication. You should either
 redesign your logic to spend less time in critical sections (recommended) or
 acquire this lock with tryLock(time, timeUnit) method call, with sufficient
 time specified.
 - Segment(s) in your Chronicle Map are very large, and iteration over them
 takes more than 60 seconds. In this case you should
 acquire this lock with tryLock(time, timeUnit) method call, with longer
 timeout specified.
 - This is a dead lock. If you perform multi-key queries, ensure you acquire
 segment locks in the order (ascending by segmentIndex()), you can find
 an example here: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#multi-key-queries

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to acquire the lock in 60 seconds.
Possible reasons:
 - The lock was not released by the previous holder. If you use contexts API,
 for example map.queryContext(key), in a try-with-resources block.
 - This Chronicle Map (or Set) instance is persisted to disk, and the previous
 process (or one of parallel accessing processes) has crashed while holding
 this lock. In this case you should use ChronicleMapBuilder.recoverPersistedTo() procedure
 to access the Chronicle Map instance.
 - A concurrent thread or process, currently holding this lock, spends
 unexpectedly long time (more than 60 seconds) in
 the context (try-with-resource block) or one of overridden interceptor
 methods (or MapMethods, or MapEntryOperations, or MapRemoteOperations)
 while performing an ordinary Map operation or replication. You should either
 redesign your logic to spend less time in critical sections (recommended) or
 acquire this lock with tryLock(time, timeUnit) method call, with sufficient
 time specified.
 - Segment(s) in your Chronicle Map are very large, and iteration over them
 takes more than 60 seconds. In this case you should
 acquire this lock with tryLock(time, timeUnit) method call, with longer
 timeout specified.
 - This is a dead lock. If you perform multi-key queries, ensure you acquire
 segment locks in the order (ascending by segmentIndex()), you can find
 an example here: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#multi-key-queries

    at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.BigSegmentHeader.deadLock(BigSegmentHeader.java:59)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.BigSegmentHeader.updateLock(BigSegmentHeader.java:231)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapIterationContext$UpdateLock.lock(CompiledMapIterationContext.java:768)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapIterationContext.forEachSegmentEntryWhile(CompiledMapIterationContext.java:3810)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapIterationContext.forEachSegmentEntry(CompiledMapIterationContext.java:3816)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapIterator.fillEntryBuffer(ChronicleMapIterator.java:61)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapIterator.hasNext(ChronicleMapIterator.java:77)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
```

It is a single-threaded and persistent map.

Comment: Github issues is clearly a better place for a (supposedly) bug report like this. I've created one: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/issues/99

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What does "It doesn't iterate successfully" mean - it is able to iterate over any entries, or stuck in the very beginning, or in the middle of iteration?

Comment: In one of your previous messages you've mentioned that you are using Chronicle Map from multiple processes (IPC), isn't this the case here? (You mentioned single-threaded but probably this is within one accessor process only, while there are more than one such processes).

Comment: Also FYI `map.forEach()` and especially `map.forEachEntry()` are much more efficient ways to iterate over a Chronicle Map than `entrySet()`.

Comment: Adding more details on the issue itself at Gihub.